# How to import json file saved in local directory (desktop) to Azure DevOps Library Variable Group using az cli?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

This is contents for the json file

```
{
  "authorized": false,
  "description": "Holds general variables",
  "name": "Var",
  "providerData": null,
  "type": "Vsts",
  "variables": {
    "Var1": {
      "isSecret": false,
      "value": "TestVar1"
        },
    "Var2": {
      "isSecret": false,
      "value": "TestVar2"
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I was trying to run.

```
$json = Get-Content -Path C:\variables\var.json out-string | out-string 

$name = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$varname = $name.variables

az pipelines variable-group create --name 'Var' --variables $varname --description 'This is a test variable' --detect false --org 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}' --project '{project name or id}'
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have multiple variables to import to Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to import json file saved in local directory (desktop) to Azure DevOps Library Variable Group using az cli?

Here is the updated script for creating a **variable group** with multiple variables inside the group, collected from the **'var.json'** file using `Azure CLI`

```
    $json = Get-Content -Path "C:\Venkat\Venkat\var.json" | Out-String
    $variableGroup = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

    $groupName = $variableGroup.name
    $description = $variableGroup.description
    $variablesObject = $variableGroup.variables
    
    $variablesHashtable = @{}
    foreach ($property in $variablesObject.PSObject.Properties) {
        $variableName = $property.Name
        $variableValue = $property.Value.value
        $variablesHashtable[$variableName] = $variableValue
    }
    $variablesString = $variablesHashtable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" }
    
    # Create variable group using Azure CLI
    az pipelines variable-group create --name $groupName --variables $variablesString --description $description --detect false --org 'https://dev.azure.com/<org-Name>' --project '<Project-name>'
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once the script is run, the `variable group` and variables are created in my project.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Venkat V, this works. Thank you. How can I run there are multiple json files to import?

Comment: Hi @albbla91, To use multiple JSON files, store them in one directory. Fetch each JSON file and use a 'for each' loop to retrieve values from each file.

$jsonFilesDirectory =  "C:\Venkat\Venkat"

$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonFilesDirectory -Filter *.json

foreach ($json in $jsonFiles) {
    $jsonnames = $json.Name
    $jsonContent = Get-Content -Path ""C:\Venkat\Venkat\$jsonnames" | Out-String

    remaining script
}

Comment: You may use the above approach. If you are unable to achieve it, please create another issue, and I will try to help you with the same.

Comment: Hi @VenkatV I was not able to import multiple json files. I have created another issue. Here is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77806383

I will mark this as an answer.

Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Hi @albbla91, I have posted an answer : [stackoverflow.com/questions/77806383](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77806383)  on how to create variable groups from multiple JSON files.

Please check and confirm the status.

Comment: Hi @Venkat V, I have reviewed the answer and it works. Thank you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To use [az pipelines variable-group create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines/variable-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-pipelines-variable-group-create), variables in format key=value space separated pairs. For example, `--variables 'var1=1' 'var2=2'`. Besides, you will need to use `az pipelines variable-group variable` commands to manage secret variables. Using the az CLI not only requires parsing the variables into the key=value format from the json file, but also processes the secret variables separately, which is a bit complicated.

As an easy way, it's suggested to use REST API [Variablegroups - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1). Then you only need to make simple modifications to your json files and do not need to deal with secret variables separately. Refer to the steps below.

**Modify your json files**

Add `variableGroupProjectReferences` to your Json file. Replace the name inside `projectReference` with your project name.

```
{
  "authorized": false,
  "description": "Holds general variables",
  "name": "Var1",
  "providerData": null,
  "type": "Vsts",
  "variables": {
    "Var1": {
      "isSecret": false,
      "value": "TestVar1"
        },
    "Var2": {
      "isSecret": false,
      "value": "TestVar2"
        },
    "Var3": {
      "isSecret": true,
      "value": "TestVar3"
    }
    },
  "variableGroupProjectReferences": [
        {
            "projectReference": {
                "name": "{project name}"
            },
            "name": "Var1",
            "description": "Holds general variables"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Run REST API in PowerShell**

Please replace the value of `organization` and `token`.

```
# Read the JSON file and convert it into a string
$jsonbody = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\variablegroup.json" | Out-String
# Define organization name and PAT
$organization = "{organization name}"
$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $jsonbody -ContentType application/json
```

**Result**

Then you can see the variable group as shown below, which contains a secret variable.
[image]

Comment: Hi @Ziyang Liu-MSFT, I get the following error when I try to run the command. PAT token has full access. 

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:6 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $jsonbo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: Please check whether the name inside `projectReference` and `organization` are correct. Please check whether the account creating the PAT has permissions to create a variable group. You can use this account to create a variable group from the UI.

Comment: Hi @Ziyang Liu-MSFT, I checked them and they are correct. I tried to call a different azure devops rest api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) and it didn't work. 

I believe your script works but something else is incorrect. 

I will create a new question on this. 

Thank you so much for your help on this.