# How to import multiple json file that are saved in local directory (desktop) to Azure DevOps Library Variable Group using az cli?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I was provided with a script ([How to import json file saved in local directory (desktop) to Azure DevOps Library Variable Group using az cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803454)) to import a single json file.

However I now need help with a script to import multiple json files to Azure DevOps variable library group.

There are three json file in the path. However the following script only imports one json file.

```
$jsonFilesDirectory = "C:\variables" 
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonFilesDirectory -Filter *.json 
foreach ($json in $jsonFiles) 
{ $jsonnames = $json.Name 
$jsonContent = Get-Content -Path "C:\variables\$jsonnames" | Out-String 

    $variableGroup = $jsonContent | ConvertFrom-Json

    $groupName = $variableGroup.name
    $description = $variableGroup.description
    $variablesObject = $variableGroup.variables
    
    $variablesHashtable = @{}
    foreach ($property in $variablesObject.PSObject.Properties) {
        $variableName = $property.Name
        $variableValue = $property.Value.value
        $variablesHashtable[$variableName] = $variableValue
    }
    $variablesString = $variablesHashtable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" } }
    
    # Create variable group using Azure CLI
    az pipelines variable-group create --name $groupName --variables $variablesString --description $description --detect false --org 'https://dev.azure.com/<org-Name>' --project '<Project-name>'
```

Comment: Hi @albbla91,I have posted an answer on how to create variable groups from multiple JSON files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to import multiple json file that are saved in local directory (desktop) to Azure DevOps Library Variable Group using az cli?

To create a **multiple variable group** with multiple variables in the **Azure DevOps Library** using multiple **JSON** files, you may use the **PowerShell** script below.

```
 $jsonFilesDirectory = "C:\variables" 
    
 $jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonFilesDirectory -Filter *.json
    
    foreach ($json in $jsonFiles) {
        $jsonContent = Get-Content -Path $json.FullName | Out-String
    
        $variableGroup = $jsonContent | ConvertFrom-Json
    
        $groupName = $variableGroup.name
        $description = $variableGroup.description
        $variablesObject = $variableGroup.variables
        
        $variablesHashtable = @{}
        foreach ($property in $variablesObject.PSObject.Properties) {
            $variableName = $property.Name
            $variableValue = $property.Value.value
            $variablesHashtable[$variableName] = $variableValue
        }
        $variablesString = $variablesHashtable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" }
        
        # Create variable group using Azure CLI
        az pipelines variable-group create --name $groupName --variables $variablesString --description $description --detect false --org 'https://dev.azure.com/Mindtreeuser' --project 'Venkat-Demo-project'
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should put `az pipelines variable-group create...` in your foreach loop.

remove `}` after `$variablesString ...`, put it after `az pipelines variable-group create...`.

script:

```
$jsonFilesDirectory = "C:\variables" 
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonFilesDirectory -Filter *.json 
foreach ($json in $jsonFiles) 
{ $jsonnames = $json.Name 
$jsonContent = Get-Content -Path "C:\variables\$jsonnames" | Out-String 

    $variableGroup = $jsonContent | ConvertFrom-Json

    $groupName = $variableGroup.name
    $description = $variableGroup.description
    $variablesObject = $variableGroup.variables
    
    $variablesHashtable = @{}
    foreach ($property in $variablesObject.PSObject.Properties) {
        $variableName = $property.Name
        $variableValue = $property.Value.value
        $variablesHashtable[$variableName] = $variableValue
    }
    $variablesString = $variablesHashtable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" } 
    
    # Create variable group using Azure CLI
    az pipelines variable-group create --name $groupName --variables $variablesString --description $description --detect false --org 'https://dev.azure.com/<org>' --project '<project>'

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @wade zhou - MSFT. This also works. Much appreciated. :)